# How to copy Excel charts to a new workbook and break external links

Tags: c#, vsto, excel-interop

I'm copying all charts from one workbook to another with the following code:

```
    using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;
    ...
    private static void CopyCharts(Excel.Workbook wbIn, Excel.Workbook wbOut)
    {
        Excel.Worksheet wsOutAfter = (Excel.Worksheet)wbOut.Sheets["Last Sheet"];
        foreach (Excel.Chart c in wbIn.Charts)
        {
            c.Copy(Type.Missing, wsOutAfter);
        }
    }
```

Each chart references data on a sheet in the source workbook ("wbIn"). The trouble with this is that the Chart.Copy command preserves those links, so now the charts in the destination workbook ("wbOut") contain external links to wbIn.

To get rid of the external links, I'd like to iterate over all the series in each destination chart and update the XValues and Values to point to the destination data sheet. Here's what I have so far:

```
    private static void CopyCharts(Excel.Workbook wbIn, Excel.Workbook wbOut)
    {
        Excel.Worksheet wsOutAfter = (Excel.Worksheet)wbOut.Sheets["Plot Items"];
        foreach (Excel.Chart c in wbIn.Charts)
        {
            string chartName = c.Name;
            c.Copy(Type.Missing, wsOutAfter);
            Excel.SeriesCollection sc = (Excel.SeriesCollection)c.SeriesCollection();
            foreach (Excel.Series s in sc)
            {
                Excel.Range r = (Excel.Range)s.XValues;
                // get string representing range, modify it and set corresponding
                // series in wbOut.Charts.Item[chartName] to something appropriate
            }
        }
    }
```

But the cast throws an exception:

```
System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'System.Object[*]' to type 'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range'.
```

How do you get and modify Series.XValues and .Values ranges?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was looking at the wrong member of Series. The member I needed to change was Series.Formula, not Series.XValues and .Values. Here's what I ended up with, iterating over the charts in the output workbook, then iterating over their series and using a regex to remove the external link text:

```
    private static void CopyCharts(Excel.Workbook wbIn, Excel.Workbook wbOut)
    {
        Excel.Worksheet wsOutAfter = (Excel.Worksheet)wbOut.Sheets["Plot Items"];
        foreach (Excel.Chart c in wbIn.Charts)
        {
            c.Copy(Type.Missing, wsOutAfter);
        }

        // break external links in new charts
        Regex externalLink = new Regex(@"\[" + wbIn.Name + @"\]");
        foreach (Excel.Chart cOut in wbOut.Charts)
        {
            Excel.SeriesCollection scOut = (Excel.SeriesCollection)cOut.SeriesCollection();
            foreach (Excel.Series sOut in scOut)
            {
                string formula = sOut.Formula;
                formula = externalLink.Replace(formula, "");
                sOut.Formula = formula;
            }
        }
    }
```

**EDIT:** But there's a better way to get rid of all external links. It's *much* faster and more comprehensive. I just call this after copying all the sheets and charts:

```
    private static void BreakAllExternalLinks(Excel.Workbook wbIn, Excel.Workbook wbOut)
    {
        Array links = (Array)wbOut.LinkSources(Excel.XlLink.xlExcelLinks);

        foreach (object o in links)
        {
            string link = o as string;
            if (link == wbIn.FullName)
                wbOut.ChangeLink(link, wbOut.FullName, Excel.XlLinkType.xlLinkTypeExcelLinks);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried to use suggested method, but have an exeption:

> Unable to cast object of type 'System.Object[*]' to type 'System.Object[]'

In C# 4.0, you will need to cast to object first. My verstion work well for me:

```
private static void BreakAllExternalLinks(Excel.Workbook wbFrom, Excel.Workbook wbTo)
    {
        Array links = (Array)((object)wbTo.LinkSources(Excel.XlLink.xlExcelLinks));
        if (links != null)
        {
            foreach (object o in links)
            {
                string link = o as string;
                if (link == wbFrom.FullName)
                {
                    wbTo.ChangeLink(link, wbTo.FullName, Excel.XlLinkType.xlLinkTypeExcelLinks);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```